# Dual stack linux router, can't forward IPv6 prefix

Tags: debian, router, dhcp, ipv6

I have a small offic here with a few workstations and I would like to implement a small server for stuff like a proxy server, samba etc.
This is the topology of said network:

```
+-----+   dynamic    +--------+        +-------------------+                 +--+workstation1
|     |  /56 prefix  |        |        |   Debian server   |        +--------+
| ISP +--------------+ Router +-+eth0+-+                   +-+eth1+-+ switch +--+workstation2
|     |   dynamic    |        |        | (squid,dhcp,etc.) |        +--------+
+-----+ IPv4 address +--------+        +-------------------+                 +--+workstationX
```

I would like to have the server assign global (maybe local as well) IPv6 addresses and private IPv4 addresses to all devices connected to eth1 via the switch. I have been able to get NAT masquerading working with dnsmasq and iptables but I can't get IPv6 traffic or even distributing IPv6 addresses to work. The router has three different settings in the IPv6 DHCP server tab:

- assign DNS server only
- assign DNS server and IPv6 prefix to downstream routers (**what I assume should be enabled**)
- assign DNS server, IPv6 prefix to downstream routers and IPv6 address

I tried following [this guide.](https://hveem.no/using-dnsmasq-for-dhcpv6) It describes how to set up a DHCPv6 server with dnsmasq. I have a working eth0 which gets a global, unique local and a link local address. But my eth1 interface never gets a global IPv6 address, only a link-local one. The devices behind the server all have a working IPv4 address but I can't set the IP to a static one because the prefix is dynamic and changes every night. Currently I'm stuck at this point.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/D5Khy9kP) are my configuration files.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use an OpenWRT-based router, which is capable of doing this. Even a reflashed home router will do. Debian has absolutely no software included which can send IPv6 prefixes downstream. Nor, as far as I know, does _any_ other distribution.

Comment: You appear to have two layers of routers with dynamically assigned IPv6 addresses in your setup. In order for that to work `Router` has to act both as DHCPv6 client and server. `Router` must act as DHCPv6 client to request delegation of the /56 from the ISP. It must also act as DHCPv6 server to delegate a /60 out of that /56 to the Debian server. I have no idea whether the software you are running on your routers support such a configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way. My interface eth0 got it's IP because of the enabled net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra=2 in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. The wide-dhcpv6-client tried setting eth0 address again, but it has already been set by the router advertisement. So if you want wide-dhcpv6-client to set the ip only to the internal interface (`eth1` in my case) you have to omit the

```
id-assoc na 1 {
    # id-assoc for eth1
};
```

part from the posted tutorial. Otherwise dhcp6c will stop after seeing that the address is already in use.

### This is what my dhcp6c.conf looks like now

```
interface eth0 {
        send ia-pd 1;
        request domain-name;
        request domain-name-servers;
        script "/etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6c-script";
};

id-assoc pd 1 {
        prefix ::/64 infinity;
        prefix-interface eth1 {
                sla-len 0;
                sla-id 1;
                ifid 1;
        };
};
```

Now everything works like a charm.
I hope this information helps anyone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign an IPv6 address to `eth1` as it won't be able to autoconfigure.  Pick an `/64` address from your `/56` although you may be able to use your `/56`.  I've used the prefix `2001:0db8:a1b2:c2d3::/64` in the example below.

```
# This is an IPv6 interface
iface eth1 inet6 static
    address  2001:0db8:a1b2:c2d3::1
    netmask  64
```

Comment: Unfortunately the prefix changes everytime the router reconnects (reboot or every 24 hours). But the bigger problem is that even after a reboot the static ip isn't shown with `ip addr`. It shows the global ip and so on on eth0 and only the link-local on eth1.

Comment: @Leo Your provider should be providing a static IPv6 address with /64 or /56 range for your use.  Otherwise, consider using a tunnel broker for IPv6.   You should firewall your global IP addresses as you will not any protection from an NAT.